# impression tracking with double click videos?

Tags: ads, double-click

I need to generate my click / impression URL's dynamically. Is there a way of adding impression tracking to a double click video tag? I understand with clicks, the "click=" followed by the URL would do, is there an equivalent for impression tracking?

```
here is an example of an ad tag:
http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/N6103.762836.GOINGOFFSCRIPT.COM/B5926988;sz=300x250click=%dfaurl%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Impression tracking should be built in to each request made to the DoubleClick tag. You should be able to login to DoubleClick to see the impressions recorded on that tag.

If you can't login to DoubleClick (did an advertiser send you this tag?) then you will need your own Ad Server software to manage the tags you receive, and that software will report on the impressions of those ads.

Answer (score 0):

if being site served, you'll need to create a 1x1 impression tag and a 1x1 click tag and have the publisher implement. You can also use "tracking ads;" which will track both, but only charge you for the greater cost (impressions or clicks) instead of both.